# Artifactory server (Docker image) behind nginx is not working properly

Tags: docker, nginx, https, artifactory

I am using the Docker image of Artifactory and I use nginx as the reverse proxy.

I also use this kind of setup with different images. However this time, the webpage is different with and without nginx.

On the left side: the normal behavior (without nginx) and on the right side: the webpage with nginx.

[image]

This is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name artifactory.daad.mobi;

  ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location /{
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
     proxy_pass_header Server;
     proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
}
```

Is something wrong with it?

Comment: Does the console say anything? Any warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem: Cloudflare.

With the cache enabled, the css problem seems to persist. And automagically, when I disable it, everything works well.

So simple solution: disable the cache if you are using Cloudflare